# Hazelcast backups are not removed when entry expires

Tags: hazelcast

I have an embedded Hazelcast 5.1.3 and I am having some troubles with entry expiration.

Map config:

```
hz.getConfig().addMapConfig(new MapConfig("session_map")
                        .setInMemoryFormat(InMemoryFormat.OBJECT)
                        .setBackupCount(1)
                        .setAsyncBackupCount(0)
                        .setStatisticsEnabled(true));
```

My entries are websocket sessions which contains some user specific data. By default, there is no TTL or Max Idle time. When a user disconnect, I set a TTL (30s) to the entry just in case that user connects back within the TTL timeout so I can restore the session.

When the entry expire, the entry is removed from the map (so there is no owner for the entry) but the entry backup is still present on the replica node.

So when I crash a node, the other node will recover backups which were expired and they are not valid anymore.

So my question is, why the backups are never removed when entry expires ?? Is there any settings that I am missing ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Might be a bug. Are you able to confirm with simpler code ? A [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ideally ?

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to reproduce the problem in a new project so I did some further investigation and I found the problem.

In my code, I registered EntryExpiredListener to cleanup the session when it expires. I did not noticed that this session cleanup actually call an Entry processor which tries to modify the session in the IMap. This causes that the backup node refuse the update with: hazelcast Received a periodic member update, ignoring... Version 2. After removing this call to entry processor, backups are removed correctly when a session expire.